# What is the command line arguments to compile an SQR report using PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, hyperion, sqr

I am trying to compile an SQR report using PostgreSQL. Here is my command line for Oracle:

```
C:\hyperion\SQR\bin\SQR\Server\Oracle\bin\sqr.exe LogAsRun.sqr ads/ads@gabdbg -RS -M sqrsize.dat
```

What would be the connectivity argument for PostgreSQL? I need to replace the `ads/ads@gabdbg` argument with one that will connect to PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. When installing SQR there is an option to install for different databases. While they don't have PostgreSQL they do have ODBC. So I installed SQR for ODBC.

I then had to go to the PostgreSQL site to download the ODBC drivers: https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/

I downloaded the MSI for 32-bit PostgreSQL. SQR will not use 64-bit. Here is the zip file I downloaded: "psqlodbc_11_01_0000-x86.zip".

I then setup a system ODBC DSN called "SCRIBE_POSTGRESQL". My command line now looks like this:

```
C:\hyperion\SQR\bin\SQR\Server\ODBC\bin\sqr.exe LogAsRun.sqr SCRIBE_POSTGRESQL -RS -M sqrsize.dat
```

Note the source of the sqr.exe comes from the ODBC folder. Also the connection parameter is the name of the ODBC DSN "SCRIBE_POSTGRESQL". Everything else stays the same.

Also you can specify the user name and password for the ODBC dsn in the SQR command line: So an alternative command line would be:

```
C:\hyperion\SQR\bin\SQR\Server\ODBC\bin\sqr.exe LogAsRun.sqr SCRIBE_POSTGRESQL/[username]/[password] -RS -M sqrsize.dat
```